# Passing arguments in RDP call

Tags: rdp, remoteapp

I have a program which takes some arguments. I have to expose this app remotely as an RDP icon.
 One solution to this seems to have different batch file and expose all batch file a separate app. But i want only one RDP icon. 
What is the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For Win2003, in `mstsc` advanced settings, set the command line in "Run this program upon connection" and "save as..." to an `.rdp` file.

Win2008r2 will not allow you to do this, you'll need to first set up the app to be used as RemoteApp, see [Overview of RemoteApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can always create RDP file, but the main concern is to pass arguments while initializing a remote app from RDP file

Comment: I said "set the _command line_ in <settings>". This means you can put the entire command line there, complete with arguments.